# QlikSense: Carriage return each concatenated value in single cell

Tags: qliksense

I have 3 columns that contain a concatenated output. For example, here's one output as it exists as a SQL result: `Baclofen  (0   mCg/mL) Baclofen  (380 mCg/mL) Bupivacaine HCl  (5   mg/mL) HYDROmorphone HCl  (6.6 mg/mL)`

So what it currently looks like in QlikSense:

[image]

And what I want it to look like, after shrinking the column width, but of course the issues are:

1. Column width based on values varies, so this won't work for every cell
2. It cuts off the last value in this example (the HYDROmorphone HCl)

[image]

Is there a way to format Qlik so that each of these values naturally goes to the next line and they all sit cleanly in the same cell?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to discover an answer to this. In my SQL, I added a char(10) and char(13) between each value, replacing the space I had (for some, a comma may be delimiting the values):

```
select ProductName = ProductName1 + char(10) + char(13) + ProductName2 + char(10) + char(13)
```

What this does is add an ASCII carriage return. You could probably get away with just a char(10), btw.

Next, clicking on the target table in Qlik, then selecting Appearance, then Presentation, then Styling, then Chart, I was able to manually assign the row height:

[image]

And now it is perfect:

[image]